# Raspberry PI 3 usb boot is not working when multiple usb devices are connected

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi3, boot

Raspberry PI 3 is not booting if multiple usb devices are connected along with the bootable one. But when only the bootable usb is connected it is booting normally.
What will be the best possible solution?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a way to solve it ?

Comment: @2t0m No, not solved yet :(

Answer (score 2):

Your Rpi isn't getting enough power - It can't power itself + the USB devices.

Do the math of how much power your USB devices require + 2A for the Pi itself. Though you can't go over 2.5Amp..

Comment: Is it a  comment or an answer

Comment: It is not a power issue, power is sufficient.